# Releasing maven multi module artifacts to Nexus from Jenkins

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

I have a parent maven project with 4 modules as

```
<modules>
    <module>../module1</module>
    <module>../module2</module>
    <module>../module3</module>
    <module>../module4</module>
</modules>
```

and when I build the parent project, all the 4 sub modules are built fine.

Module1, 2 and 3 are only dependent modules and I don't want to push the artifacts generated from these modules to Nexus when parent project is built on Jenkins. But I need to push the artifact from module4 as that will generate the main artifact deployed as an application.

Is there any way to achieve this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Usually you deploy everything. Why do you want to avoid to publish modules 1 to 3?

Comment: Hi @JFMeier, Thanks for your response. Actually modules 1 - 3 are used by other projects also similar to module 4 and everytime I build these main modules, it releases 1 version for the modules 1-3 and so I want to avoid it

Comment: That sounds strange. If the modules 1-3 are used in other projects, shouldn't they be in Nexus, so that the other projects can use them? Or do you copy/paste the code?

Comment: You are right, ideally they should be on Nexus, but I am looking if I can build locally on Jenkins and push the main modules. Also, when modules 1-3 are built, new artifacts would be released to Nexus for these modules and I can't find a way to include these new versions dynamically in module4

Comment: Are you using SNAPSHOT versions? Modules can be in SNAPSHOT version until you really want to deploy the next release.

Comment: Yes, I use snapshots on local system, but on Jenkins they are release versions

Comment: I still do not completely understand the structure. Do you have a second multi-module project that duplicates the code of modules 1-3? Or do you have different module parent poms for the same modules?

Comment: Yes, there is one more module by name module5 which also uses the modules 1-3. Modules 1-3 are web projects and module 4 and 5 are ear projects and so when the build is done, WAR files are added in EAR artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Just put modules 1,2,3,4,5 into one Maven multi-module project and build and deploy the m together. This is cleanest approach, aligned with the Maven philosophy.

Comment: Thanks @JFMeier, we have decided to follow the route of pushing all the modules to Nexus and not building them locally. As you had mentioned that is the cleanest approach :)